# error no eligible devices for app install,how can I solve this?

Tags: android, google-play

I write a android app, I install my app to my samsung tablet 3 by using eclipse, it works fine,
but when I put my app to google market , And I enter market with my tablet I want to install my app but it says **no eligible devices for app install** 
what is the problem I do not understand.

my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"  
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true"  
    />
```

Please help me about that
thanks.

Comment: Does your tablet has calling(sim) facility.

Comment: If you app supports tablet you should remove the support-screens element.

Comment: @GauravGupta no my tablet has not calling(sim) facility why?

Comment: @StephaneMathis why support-screen elements I must delete? I write them to support tablet?

Comment: I am not very much sure about it, but does "LOCATION" permission are dependent on SIM/network provider info?

Comment: I do not know actually

Comment: You do not need the support-screens element. By default all apps are available for tablets and need to add something extra to limit the usage on phone only.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the Camera permission that blocks the installation.
As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features), you can add the fallowing element and it should work :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: why you think the problem is camera, because my tablet has camera?

Comment: Does it have autofocus ?

Comment: You can play with the manifest and upload several apk file without publishing them. You'll get a screen which shows what is the difference with the previous apk file and if more or less devices are supported.

Comment: My tablet has no vibrate, is it the real problem?
so how can I write  **<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />** for vibrate is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so. But just change your manifest and see what the problem is with the Developer Console.

Comment: How can I understand ? if I put vibrate it does not work but it is not give force close error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is vibrate permission. I remove that permission and vibrate code in my project it works and seen my tablet on market.

Comment: Weird, there isn't supposed to be a vibrate feature or filtering on it per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/QMs8Hiww9Qs .